# Changing Series Name and Color in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, series

I have multiple series rendered in my chart but I am not able to figure out how to change the name or other attributes for each series.  The legend just has them as series 1, series 2, and series 3.

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('decodeseries.php', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
         $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'        
            },
            yAxis: {title: {text: 'Wave Height ( In Ft )'}},
            xAxis: {type: 'datetime'},

            title : {
                text : '5 Day Forecast'
            },



            series: data [{
                name: 'Location 1',
                data: data

            }, {
                name: 'Location 2',
                data: data


            }, {
                name: 'Location 3',
                data: data


            }]
        });

    });

});
        </script>
```

JSon:

```
[{"data":[[1385510400000,0.88],[1385521200000,0.722]]},
{"data":[[1385510500000,0.98],[1385521400000,0.752]]},
{"data":[[1385510600000,1.88],[1385521500000,0.792]]}]
```

This actually doesn't show the chart, but its what I have been trying so far.  The chart works with the above JSON when I simply use the following:

```
series: data
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the color/name of a data series in your `data` element you need to give it those properties. As near as I can tell your `data` JSON is actually composed of 3 series of data:

```
[
{"data":[[1385510400000,0.88],[1385521200000,0.722]]},
{"data":[[1385510500000,0.98],[1385521400000,0.752]]},
{"data":[[1385510600000,1.88],[1385521500000,0.792]]}
]
```

I would change it (however it was made) to this:

```
[
{"name":"Location 1", "color": "acolor", "data":[[1385510400000,0.88],[1385521200000,0.722]]},
{"name":"Location 2", "color": "anothercolor", "data":[[1385510500000,0.98],[1385521400000,0.752]]},
{"name":"Location 3", "color": "yetanothercolor", "data":[[1385510600000,1.88],[1385521500000,0.792]]}
]
```

You chart code above does not render because you are doing:

```
    series: data [{
        name: 'Location 1',
        data: data
    }, {
        name: 'Location 2',
        data: data
    }, {
        name: 'Location 3',
        data: data
    }]
```

And it is trying to assign the `data` property in `data` to `series.data` which is not valid. Essentially your are saying make each of the 3 series.data = series.data.data.

Using my example above do something like :

```
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'        
            },
            yAxis: {title: {text: 'Wave Height ( In Ft )'}},
            xAxis: {type: 'datetime'},  
            title : {
                text : '5 Day Forecast'
            },
            series: data 
        });
```

Comment: Can I also control the chart "type" for each series this way as well?  (line, spline, area, etc)

Comment: Correct. Please check the API documentation here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series. Lots of good info and examples.